# Error in Visual Studio 2013: "No exports were found that match the constraint"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I don't know what happen with my Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

When I opened my project, it displayed this message:

> No exports were found that match the constraint:
>   ContractName
>
> Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ISolutionAttachedCollection.Service
>
> RequiredTypeIdentity 
>     Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ISolutionAttachedCollection.Service

I am really confused. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984580/getting-error-in-no-valid-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint), but it didn't solve my problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to help you without knowing:

- the complete list of installed extensions,
- the exact Visual Studio 2013 version,
- the exact Windows version,
- a brief reproduction script.

The most important clue you can get about the root cause, can be seen in Visual Studio Activity Log. I suggest starting Visual Studio with activity logging enabled ([`devenv.exe /log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms241272)), reproducing the error and checking the log.

- [How to: Use the Activity Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166359),
- [Troubleshooting Extensions with the Activity Log](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-with-the-activity-log.aspx).

Comment: it really helped to fix the problem. The main problem and its solution can be found here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574089/microsoft-visual-studio-package-did-not-loaded

Comment: I had the same problem/warning, I delete all the files in %AppData%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\
and it worked for me once again.
Good luck!

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is possible - see the answer by c0d3p03t, which worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28487139/127434

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem, so I shut down Visual Studio 2013, renamed the folder

C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

to ComponentModelCache-old, and restarted Visual Studio which rebuilt the ComponentModelCache folder and all is back to normal.

Comment: Worked like a charm! This happened when I opened a VS 2010 winform project. Thanks!

Comment: Bravo!  Thank you for taking the time to post this solution.  Works well!

Comment: Or more generally, on Windows Vista or later, the first part, `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local`, is [`%LOCALAPPDATA%`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/appdata/info) (environment variable). So `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio` would lead close to it, whatever the version of Visual Studio it is.

Comment: On older versions of Windows and Visual Studio it might be near `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`, e.g. `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\DotNetComponents.cache`.

Comment: Thanks. This works for my Visual Studio 2013 - Win form project

Answer (score -1):

If you download Visual Studio 2013 from Microsoft you will find the path `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WDexpress\12.0\ComponentModelCache`.

You should remove the file `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache`.

Then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you sure about that? [c0d3p03t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847640/error-in-visual-studio-2013-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint/28487139#28487139) says `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache`.